# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame} Error

Tags: beamer, errors

What is wrong here? I got an error:

> ```
> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}
> ```

```
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \maketitle
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,]{dane_zamkniecie.eps}
      \caption{Close prices from 1950-01-03 to 2013-12-05\\}
      \label{fig6}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the closing \\ from the caption: `\caption{Close prices from 1950-01-03 to 2013-12-05}`.

Comment: It seems you are using `beamer`: then there's no need for `figure` and `\caption`: just give the frame a title and include the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main solutions. The first one is given by @moewe in the comments.

The other is to load the caption package (`\usepackage{caption}`), which will get rid of the error. This is the best option if you want to add a break line in the caption (which was perhaps your original intention).

If you do not want to load another package and still want to add more space after the figure, I would suggest to use `\vspace{}` after the figure. This however works for one figure only. If you want to change the spacing for every figure, use the suggestion by @Fran, and set `\belowcaptionskip`. See more about it [here](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/444.htm~mainFrame).

Comment: The best solution usually is to not have a line-break within the caption without having a separate caption for LOF.

Comment: @TeXnician "This is the best option **if** you want to add a break line in the caption" Surely, whether having a break in a caption is optimal or not, that's another matter.

Comment: If you do not want to load another package and still want to add more space after the figure, I would suggest  set  `\belowcaptionskip`.

Comment: @Fran Correct. That would set it for **every** figure. My recommendation is more appropriate for a one-off. Added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: @luchonacho That is the idea, but is valid in any case. Inside a float only change the space after the caption of that float and there are not problem to  change  `\belowcaptionskip` as much as necessary in the body (outside of any float) to change only the  followings floats (except the lack of consistency in the  document layout).

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}` does not resolve the issue for me if I want multiple line breaks inside a caption.